# Android convert Class in dex to anonymous name

Tags: android, dex, android-proguard, dex2jar

When I decompiled my `apk` using `dex2jar-2.0` I could get my original code only.

But for some popular APK, when I followed the same steps I got Class names like A, B, AB etc

How to make my apk also secure like those `apks`

Please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for code obfuscation. Take a look at this article http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/help/proguard.html